# PostgreSQL Query to change columns to uppercase

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration

I am working on a mySQL to PostgreSQL database migration using pgloader. One of the issues I am facing is that my application is looking for any tables beginning with `"ao_"` to be `"AO_"` which I was able to solve by making them all uppercase, however the corresponding columns also need to be uppercase.

Is there a good way to make JUST the `"AO_"` table columns be all uppercase. It does not seem very efficient to just do this for 400 tables with approximately 10 columns per table:

```
ALTER TABLE "AO_54307E_QUEUE" RENAME project_id TO "PROJECT_ID";
```

Is there maybe some kind of wildcard we could use to just grab the "AO_" tables and then have all the columns be uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you against doing it, and I am quoting from the [**documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case.
>   If you want to write portable applications you are
>   advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.

So, quoting "*JUST the "AO_" table columns be all uppercase*" seems like a **bad** idea.

If you still wish to proceed, you may use a loop through `information_schema.columns` and run dynamic `ALTER` statements.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;

 BEGIN

for rec IN (  SELECT column_name,table_name,table_schema 
               FROM  information_schema.columns 
               WHERE   table_name  like 'AO_%'     
               AND     column_name like 'ao_%'  )
  LOOP

   EXECUTE format ( 'ALTER TABLE  %I.%I RENAME %I TO %I' ,            
                     rec.table_schema,rec.table_name,rec.column_name,
                     upper(rec.column_name)) ;
   RAISE NOTICE 'COLUMN %  in Table %.% RENAMED', 

rec.column_name,rec.table_schema,rec.table_name;


  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e9665be02c68636c16daeeb92e0c5f9a)

Comment: Awesome! This was very helpful! Thank you!